# XML / PHP - If search response is empty

Tags: php, xml

I have a function that when you search for a postcode or airport it displays an array of results in a textbox as follows (which is how it should work):

[image]

This works fine until I put something 'random' in the address search, and for some reason it still populates the dropdown menu even though there are no results in the search list (see below):

[image]

From the above search, in the firebug console I get the following response:

`No results found, please try a different post code.)`

and the following XML response:

`XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: moz-nullprincipal:{90e67c6c-c3a7-497c-a4df-6045472afde6} Line Number 1, Column 1:`

`No results found, please try a different post code.`

Here is the code below:

```
public static function getAddressByPostcode($postcode) {

    $addressArray = array();

    $uri = 'http://[ipaddress]:[port]/?pc='.$postcode; // Send to Computer

    $response = CurlController::request($uri);

    if ($response != false) {

        // Clean html
        $response = strip_tags($response);

        $deserializedAddressArray = unserialize($response); 

        // Get result set count
        self::set_resultcount(count($deserializedAddressArray));

        if (self::get_resultcount() > 0) {

            foreach ($deserializedAddressArray as $address) {

                if(!isset($address['company']) || $address['company'] == '') {
                    $address['company'] = '';
                    $addr_cat = 1;
                } else {
                    $addr_cat = 2;
                }

                if(!isset($address['no'])) $address['no'] = '';
                if(!isset($address['street'])) $address['street'] = '';
                if(!isset($address['locality'])) $address['locality'] = '';
                if(!isset($address['town'])) $address['town'] = '';
                if(!isset($address['postcode'])) $address['postcode'] = '';

                if(!isset($address['Longitude'])) {
                    $address['Longitude'] = '';
                } else {
                    $address['Longitude'] = ($address['Longitude'] / 1000) / 3600;
                }

                if(!isset($address['Latitude'])) {
                    $address['Latitude'] = '';
                } else {
                    $address['Latitude'] = ($address['Latitude'] / 1000) / 3600;
                }



                $addressObject = new Address($addr_cat,$address['company'],$address['no'],$address['street'],
                                             $address['locality'],$address['town'],$address['postcode'],
                                             $address['Latitude'],$address['Longitude']);

                ## Swapped lat and long around as field spec on response is wrong

                ## TODO - Add validation for address object

                // Add address into addresses array
                array_push($addressArray,$addressObject);

            }

            self::getAddressesAsXML($addressArray);

        } else {

            self::$text_response .= "No results found, please try a different post code. \r\n";
            echo self::$text_response;

        }

    } else {

        self::$text_response .= "Address server is taking too long to respond, please try again later. \r\n";
        echo self::$text_response;

    }

}
```

If anybody could help me with this, it would be much appreciated. I can't seem to figure out why it is populating an empty array and not displaying an error alert message instead.

Comment: can u post a "var_dump()" of the empty "$deserializedAddressArray"?
maybe its not fully empty

Comment: I can do var_dump($deserializedAddressArray); for `self::$text_response .= "No results found, please try a different post code. \r\n";` the first else statement, but for the second it says its an undefined variable and i'm unsure why?

Comment: u have to figure out why he says there are some results. Thats why u need to print the var_dump of your response. I can still see nothing now sorry. I guess he says there are some contents because there is something little nasty in your response.

Answer (score 0):

You check if there are any results :  if (self::get_resultcount() > 0) { }
And when you close that IF statement you have self::getAddressesAsXML($addressArray);

When you have no results, i think that xml array thingy doesn't work, maybe you should add it into the IF statement.

Im not sure if this will work tho! worth to try